# .bat that calls AFUDOS to flash BIOS

Tags: windows, bios, batch, batch-file

I've got a .bat file that is supposed to flash the BIOS on my laptop. It reads as follows:

```
@AFUDOS T.105 /p /b /n /e /x /reboot
```

Before actually running it, I would like to unterstand what it does. More specifically:

1. AFUDOS obviously calls AFUDOS.exe, but what does the @ do and why is it not necessary to specify the file extension?
2. T.105 I guess is the BIOS-.rom file which also lies in the same directory. Is that right?
3. All the parameters (p b n e x) are given to AFUDOS I guess? What do they mean? Is AFUDOS case sensitive in these parameters?

I found the following info on some of the (capital?) parameters, but to be honest, I don't understand what it means:

B - Update Boot Block

N - Update NVRAM

C - Destroy System CMOS

Remark: the files are from the manufacturer so I expect them to do the right thing, I would just like to understand what exactly I would be doing to my laptop when running this .bat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> AFUDOS obviously calls AFUDOS.exe, but what does the @ do and why is it not necessary to specify the file extension?

The `@` causes the command not to be echoed to the screen before it's executed. The extension doesn't need to be specified because that is the DOS way. Otherwise, you'd have to know whether a command was built in or not in order to execute it, and that would be a bit tedious. (Do you really want to type `dir.exe` or `rename.com` to get a directory or rename a file?)

> T.105 I guess is the BIOS-.rom file which also lies in the same directory. Is that right?

Yes.

> All the parameters (p b n e x) are given to AFUDOS I guess? What do they mean? Is AFUDOS case sensitive in these parameters?

AFUDOS is not case-sensitive.

p = update main bios image
b = update book block
n = update NVRAM
e = update embedded controller block
x = do not do extra checks on ROM compatibility

Comment: Although it's not what DOS uses, it might be worth looking into the [PathExt](http://environmentvariables.org/PathExt) environment variable, about "executable file extensions". /edit: Found a [KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/35284) about DOS.

Comment: @David Schwartz thanks, one more thing though: does the x parameter mean that I could flash the BIOS on a non-compatible laptop with this .bat and ruin it?

Comment: @user35915 I doubt it for two reasons. One, the `q` parameter wasn't specified, so it's interactive and will give you a chance to refuse. Two, there are still basic compatibility checks done, and I believe those are sufficient.